# How to execute stored procedure parameter that is a SQL query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I'm trying to pass in a dynamic SQL query to a stored procedure and inside that SQL Server stored procedure I need to run the query and send the results to another stored procedure for another process. I know I don't have the syntax correct but is there a way that this can work?

This would be my stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.uspTaskRouter 
    @sqlCommand nvarchar(MAX),
    @uspName nvarchar(MAX),
    @dataType nvarchar(MAX)
```

And something like this would be inside the procedure:

```
SELECT * 
INTO #queryTable 
    EXEC (@sqlCommand)

EXEC @uspName #queryTable, @dataType
```

Comment: Have you had a look at `sys.sp_executesql`?

Comment: Not easily, since you cannot select * into a new table from dynamic sql exec, and if you do it inside of dynamic sql, it will dissapear. I think it sounds like you're trying the so called inner-platform effect, ie. emulating database queries inside a database. What you can do is create a semi-permanent tables that are dropped in the end, and passing name of that table as a parameter, and then using dynamic sql to access it. But yeah, since you ask, it's probably a bad idea :)

Comment: You have a real danger of SQL injection with this approach, imagine if the command passed in starting removing tables from your database. Its not usually best practice to write such generic SQL procedures.

Comment: As @siggemannen said the biggest hurdle is saving results. It can be overcome but it requires a lot of ugly code.

Comment: Where will those sql queries come from - a "front end"?  As already stated this is open to abuse through sql injection and has strong "code smell". Over use of dynamic sql by itself is something to avoid - passing in whole queries as parameters is just awful.